# Activiting joomla 2.5 cache for logged users

Tags: php, caching, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a problem with joomla 2.5 caching system. As you know, by default system logged-in users does not use cache but, I must make them use the cache too. I tried several things like deleting

```
if ($user->get('guest') && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
        $this->_cache->setCaching(true);
    }
```

from plugins\system\cache\cache.php but, none worked. When I do that, it forces logged-in users to logout. When I re-apply the original code, they automatically sign-in again. I could not find any solution for 3 days, so here I'm.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: First, don't hack core files, copy the plugin, rename it, and make the changes there, install and enable your new one and disable the old one. I'm not sure why you would delete that whole block and not just the first condition.

Comment: I know only basic coding, not skillful, but I already did what you said before, nothing changed though. It still logouts people.